# Сервер Debian - переполнение памяти

Tags: linux, debian, mongodb, vps, pm2

Упал сайт. Год работал и вдруг упал. Я удивился, т.к. у меня стоит `pm2` и если че, все равно должен был его поднять. Кроме сайта `pm2` поддерживал еще десяток поддоменов. Зашел на сервер - список поддерживаемых процессов `pm2` оказался пуст. 
Автозавершение командной строки (табуляция)  - не работает. Проверил память - она оказалась забита 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

перешел в директорию `dev` увидел там такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

детализация выдала такое 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала подумал, что стал жертвой атаки какой-нибудь (хотя кому я нужен), а потом, когда погуглил немного про `TTY` - у меня появились сомнения. 
Какие Ваши варианты произошедшего?

**UPD**:в дополнение к коvментариям

Но наибольший ужас твориться в логах `pm2`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD.2**: Моя версия произошедшего: по какой-то причине произошел сбой в работе `MongoDB` (не исключено внешнее вмешательство). `Pm2` пытался восстановить работу БД, однако это не получалось. Информация об этом записывалась в логи `pm2`. Эти логи заполнили все свободное пространство файловой системы. В итоге перестал работать и сам `pm2`  и все процессы, которые он поддерживал

Comment: А причем тут /dev. в нем вообще нет ничего, что бы занимало диск. там файлы устройств. А вот какие нибудь логи, обычно находящиеся в /var/log вполне могли занять весь диск

Comment: А вообще лучше посмотреть `du -h -s -x /*` что бы понять где именно сколько места занято.

Comment: @Mike, благодарю за подсказку. В логах действительно твориться что-то ужасное). 4 Gb занимают

Comment: На будущее. Поставь себе `ncdu` и погугли что такое `logrotate`.

Comment: 1. вопрос не верный - не память, а место на корневой фс, 2. вместо картинок можно ведь текст было запостить. 3. 4гб логов за год это вообщето маловато у меня генерируют сервисы 10гб в час... 4. стоит беспокоится восновном о всем кроме `/proc /sys /dev /run` в большинстве своем они монтируются в памяти.

Comment: @donRumata, Hellseher - спасибо за подсказки